# Merging two database into single database

Tags: c#-3.0, sql-server-express

I have deployed same application in two different computers. Now i need to merge both data from two different database into single database.
The application is developed using c# .net and uses sql express 2008.
The problem arised because i could not use the application over LAN.
So i need to merge the two database into one.
So please help me to solve the problem to merge it.
I also need to run the application over LAN but the sqlbrowser doesnot start and i have searched the internet for the answer but i haven't been lucky.

thank you, waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you want to take will depend largely on your schema, but [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx) should likely be useful. It would let you define rules for resolving conflicts and merging your data.

As for accessing your data over the LAN, [this post](http://www.datamasker.com/SSE2005_NetworkCfg.htm) has a good overview of what it takes to enable remote access to your SQL Server Express.